# Java: Take anonymous class outside

Tags: java, design-patterns, anonymous-class

I have a situation presented below:

```
Class C1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o = // new object of some class
        delegate(new C2() {             // C2 is an abstract class or interface
            public void delegateLogic() {
                Object my_o = o;  // refrences main's local variable
                // huge method body
                // object o local to main is required here  
            }
        });
    }

    private void delegate(C2 c2) {
        // method body
    }
}
```

The body of delegateLogic() is turning out to be very big. For code maintainability :

1. I want to create a concrete class from C2 and keep it outside, while still having a way to use object o in the main method.
2. Also, instance of C2 are supposed to be serializable and unfortunately object o is not serializable. So, I do not want to create a member object in C2 by passing object o in the constructor.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to make this serializable, you have to find some way to capture at least the relevant parts of `o` in a serializable form.

Comment: Plus, I do not have control over definition of class (possible classes) of o.

Comment: Can you make o a static field?

Comment: In both cases, a reference to the object o will be kept in the C2 implementation

Comment: With respect to your point 2, passing a reference to o into the constructor won't impact the serializability of C2. It's entirely up to you to decide what you wish to consider the serializable state of C2. If you decide o is transient then don't stream it out during serialization

Comment: I do not understand the questin still. you are saying `// object o local to main is required here ` you already have it and just used it `Object my_o = o;`. What exactly is the issue ?

Comment: Your existing anonymous `C2` instance if not serializable either (since it already contains an implicit reference to `o`) so there is no change in that respect when you move it outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want C2 to be able to be serialized, just declare o as transient. However, you would need to accept the fact that o will be null if it got serialized/deserialized unless you manage to serialize it manually somehow.

```
public class X extends C2 {
    private transient Object o;

    public X(Object o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    public void delegateLogic() {
        Object my_o = o;  // refrences main's local variable
        // huge method body
        // object o local to main is required here  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If C2 becomes an external class then it must have the reference to o passed to it in some form to use it in `delegateLogic`. You really only have 3 options for getting o into your C2 instance:

1. pass it in the constructor
2. use a setter method
3. pass it directly as an argument to `delegateLogic`

Which of these you choose depends on many things.

Note that storing a reference to o in a member variable of the class does not force you to serialize that reference.